# DSE Graph random connection closed exception

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

So we're running the our application with 3 node DSE cluster and singleton DSESession object. Session or connection is not closed anywhere in the codebase.

But randomly I'm getting the following error message. Almost for every 400 requests, there is a failure.

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/ipaddress:9042] Connection has been closed
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ConnectionCloseFuture.force(Connection.java:1210)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$ConnectionCloseFuture.force(Connection.java:1195)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.defunct(Connection.java:445)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.exceptionCaught(Connection.java:1128)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:280)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:259)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:280)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:259)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:88)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:280)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:259)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:251)

Code used for the connection is provided below.

```
DseCluster.Builder dseBuilder = DseCluster.builder();
dseBuilder.addContactPoints(contactPoints);
dseBuilder.withLoadBalancingPolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
    .withLocalDc("us-west-2")
    .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(3)
    .allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel()
    .build());
QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE);
dseBuilder.withQueryOptions(queryOptions);
dseBuilder.withGraphOptions(new GraphOptions().setGraphName(graphName));
DseSession dseSession = dseBuilder.build().connect();
return DseGraph.traversal(dseSession);
```

And not able to find anything else from cassandra logs also. It'll be helpful if someone faced this issue or tell me how to debug this one.

Comment: What DSE version?

Comment: It's DSE version 6.0.1

Comment: Please upgrade to at least 6.0.5 or to 6.0.latest

Comment: We're yet to find the root cause of the issue. But the problem was connection drop happens from AWS ELB in which our application backend is there. After switching to different ELB, everything works fine